# Qt 5 scaling entire windows

Tags: c++, qt

So I have a product presentation tommorow and my designer made our Qt application to be big to fit on a 720p screen... There is no time to properly fix this in a day so I am grasping at straws here but is it somehow possible to just scale everything in the qt window to 75% of the size?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using QMake, the link below has instructions about how to declare your Qt application to be *non*-DPI-aware.  I am not sure what you would do for other build systems.  Then, you could set the environment variables documented there to set a custom scaling factor for the window, and hopefully you can make it be less than 1.  I have not tried this so I am not sure if it would work.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html